# Search for a particular value in a string with commas

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2005

I have a TEXT column in my Table T and contains some values separated by Commas.

> Example
>   Columns BNFT has text values such as

```
B20,B30,B3,B13,B31,B14,B25,B29,B1,B2,B4,B5
OR 
B1,B2,B34,B31,B8,B4,B5,B33,B30,B20,B3
```

> I want to return result in my query only if B3 is present. 
>   It should not consider B30-B39 or B[1-9]3 (i.e. B13, B23 .... B93).

I tried with below query, but want to implement REGEXP or REGEXP_LIKE/INSTR etc. Haven't used them before and unable to understand also.

```
Select *
FROM T
Where BNFT LIKE '%B3,%' or BNFT LIKE '%B3'
```

Pls advise

> Procedures will not work. Query must start with Select as 1st statement.

Comment: Just to be clear. Single cell in column contain 'B20,B30,B3,B13,B31,B14,B25,B29,B1,B2,B4,B5' as string or this b20 is diffrent cell than b30?

Comment: It is a Text Column and all these are in one record.It is like a multi Value for that column separated with commas.

SO say the customer has subscribed to all benefits B1, B2, B7, etc...

Comment: Do yourself a massive favour: normalise your schema.

Comment: Its already built database. So cannot be changed. I am just querying to get data for client :) –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first advice is to fix your data structure.  Storing lists of ids in strings is a bad idea:

- You are storing numbers as strings.  That is the wrong representation.
- You are storing multiple values in a string column.  That is not using SQL correctly.
- These values are probably ids.  You cannot declare proper foreign key relationships.
- SQL does not have particularly strong string functions.
- The resulting query cannot take advantage of indexes.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.

In SQL Server, you would do:

```
where ',' + BNFT + ',' LIKE '%,33,%'
```

This question was originally tagged MySQL, which offers `find_in_set()` for this purpose:

```
Where find_in_set(33, BNFT) > 0
```

Comment: I already tried this but get this error -----  'find_in_set' is not a recognized built-in function name.. I am using ExactTarget and it supports SQL 2005 i guess

Comment: Also, its already built database. So cannot be changed. I am just querying to get data for client :)

Comment: @PankajGupta . . . The question was originally tagged MySQL, hence you got a MySQL answer.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
FROM T
Where ',' + BNFT + ',' LIKE '%,B3,%';
```

or

```
Select *
FROM T
Where CHARINDEX  (',B3,',',' + BNFT + ',') > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This can be easily achieve by CTE, REGEXP/REGEXP_Like/INSTR works better with oracle, for MS SQL Server you can try this
```

DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(100) ='B2,B34,B31,B8,B4,B5,B33,B30,B20,B3';
   SET @CSV = @CSV+',';

WITH CTE AS
   (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@CSV,1,CHARINDEX(',',@CSV,1)-1) AS VAL,   SUBSTRING(@CSV,CHARINDEX(',',@CSV,1)+1,LEN(@CSV)) AS REM 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(A.REM,1,CHARINDEX(',',A.REM,1)-1)AS VAL,  SUBSTRING(A.REM,CHARINDEX(',',A.REM,1)+1,LEN(A.REM)) 
    FROM CTE A WHERE LEN(A.REM)>=1
    ) SELECT VAL FROM CTE
    WHERE VAL='B3'